# How to plot geotiff files with xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray, geotiff

I have downloaded some data from Google Earth Engine. The data looks like the following:

```
import xarray as xr
da = xr.open_rasterio('myFile.tiff')

da
```

[image]

I can show the image but I would like to avoid to consider values that are equal to zero.

```
f,ax = plt.subplots()
da.plot(ax=ax, cmap='hot_r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`xarray` has a quite extensive `matplotlib` backend, check the [documentation](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/plotting.html) on the different plotting options.

To answer your question, you can use the `plot.imshow` method of your `DataArray` to visualize your raster (there you can also pass keywords for colormap, range, colorbar, etc. ...).

To exclude values equal (or equal and below) `0`, just run `where` before plotting, to set all values which don't comply to the specified condition to `Nan` and therefore exclude for plotting. Be aware that this will change the datatype.

One final thing, `plot.imshow` expects a `2d` array, and your dataset seems to have a 3rd dimension `band` that has only one 'layer'. You can easily drop that with `squeeze`, either before `where` or `plot.imshow`.

Here's an example:

```py
import xarray as xr

# test data
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("rasm")

# replicate 3d data array
da = ds.isel(time=0).Tair.expand_dims({"band":1})

# exclude vals below or equal to 0, squeeze to 2d and plot
da.where(da>=0).squeeze().plot.imshow(cmap="hot_r")
```

[image]